# Counting basis sets in quantum chemistry

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I have to use STO-nG (a "minimal basis set" - meaning that only one basis function is used for each atomic orbital in the atoms of which the molecule is made from). Let's take the example of a water molecule.

The water molecule has two H atoms and one O atom. Thus, we have a total of 7 orbitals (two 1s of H, one 1s of O, one 2s of O and three 2p of O). So when using STO-nG, would that then mean that three 1s type basis functions, one 2s type basis function, and 3 p-type basis functions are used, totalling at 7 basis functions, each being made up from a linear combination (LC) of n simple gaussians?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many basis functions used in STO-3G and 6-31+G\*\* for the water molecule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41163/how-many-basis-functions-used-in-sto-3g-and-6-31g-for-the-water-molecule)

Comment: @Tyberius Yes. But if you see the answers, this has not been answered.

Comment: Sorry I missed that they never explicitly answered that. But you are correct, STO-nG for water will have 7 basis functions, each of which is formed from n-Gaussians. As an aside, you could always check this using a free electronic structure program like Psi4 or ORCA. @hhsomething69

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have counted the number of basis functions correctly:

```
    #1s    #2s    #2px    #2py    #2pz    #Total
H1   1                                      1
H2   1                                      1
O    1      1       1       1       1       5
```

Which as you also counted is 7 basis functions.
As you also correctly state, each of the basis functions will be a linear combination of $n$ primitive Gaussians:

$$\phi(r)=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\exp\left(-\alpha_i\left(r-r_0\right)^2\right)$$

As you have observed that is what the $n$ in STO-$n$G denotes.